# Vs2017 + W10 CU in xaml workspace: transparent xaml preview and invisible items

Tags: xaml, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I have a problem with xaml files, when I view a xaml file, all is transparent and all items : button, textblock etc are invisible. I have visual studio 2017 and windows 10 CU, how I can resolve it? I have modified theme in dark and Xaml color in white but it's the same, Toggle artboard background is not selcted. Please help me because is hard work with this problem. Before update windows 10 to creators updates all worked fine...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I just created a new xaml preview and rebuild my old xaml step by step. This worked fine. Just copy and paste the whole xaml page won't work, so it is just a Workaround until Microsoft fixes it, i recently opend a problem via Visual Studio-Feedback.
You can try aswell to Change/create the

```
  <Grid Background="Color"> </Grid>
```

this helped me making at least something visible.

Comment: I have tried yet this option but it didn't work for me. I had to format my pc and install Windows 10 CU directly. This solution was effective. So I think that it were not a bug but there are some files that become incompatible or I don't know. Thank anyway :)